# How To Remove All Points In a CCPointArray

Tags: android, arrays, cocos2d-x

Is there a simple way to erase every point in a CCPointArray? All I can find is to use a for loop and call removeControlPointAtIndex. Even still, that didn't work and I can't delete my points. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Didn't work"? Why not? What code are you using? To my knowledge, you *do* have to remove them one-by-one.

Comment: @Eric I'm using c++. I've logged the count() function of the array. I build a grid a 700 points. I delete some through out the application. To reset, I delete them all, and create the grid again. Now I have 1400 in my count().

Comment: And, what is the code you're using to do this? I doubt it is an issue in cocos itself.

Comment: I'm using Google JNI and Eclipse.

Comment: some more code will help to trace the problem

Answer (score 8):

If you use a loop using `CCARRAY_FOREACH`, and erase elements, the loop won't work propertly. You cannot erase elements using it. Change the bubble for:

```
   while (myArray.count != 0)
```

for removing elements.

Answer (score 0):

Piperman should be correct. Go through each index and delete that certain node until the count drops to 0